# Header android 9patch

Tags: android, xml, header, nine-patch

I would like to create a full screen header for Android.
I created the image that is 70 * 480 px (& 9patch).
how can I do?
I tried using the galaxy tab .. but it does not fill the screen horizontally.
This is the code:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/aaa.bbb"
    android:id="@+id/db1_root" 
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
 <ImageView 
                android:src="@drawable/header" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    >
</ImageView>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the android:scaleType and optionally android:adjustViewBounds.  Play around with these two attributes to get the desired effect.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to add your ImageView to the xml file

```
            <shush.android.util.AspectImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/header" />
```

Add this class:

```
package shush.android.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * @author Sherif elKhatib
 *
 */
public class AspectImageView extends View {

    public AspectImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AspectImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AspectImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = width * getBackground().getIntrinsicHeight()
                / getBackground().getIntrinsicWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/aaa.bbb"
android:id="@+id/db1_root" 
android:orientation="vertical"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background">
<ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/header" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                >
</ImageView>
```